# Using this in an anonymous function in Javascript / Chrome Browswer gives error: Cannot read property 'localeCompare' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I ran into this error of "Cannot read property 'localeCompare' of undefined"

when I was trying to convert a string function of compare(String, String) to String.compare(String)

```
   let compare = (y, x) =>  y.localeCompare(x) == 0 ? true : false;  //This works

   let gender = x =>  compare("male", x) || compare("female", x);  //This  works

   String.prototype.compareTruthy = (x) => {
    this.localeCompare(x) == 0 ? true : false;
   }

   "male".compareTruthy("male") //This does not work, why?
```

I wanted to re-use this compareTruthy function for any other string comparisons I might have later on.

What am I missing in my understanding?

Comment: Arrow functions aren't a good choice for adding methods to the prototype...

Comment: Hello, can you please upvote this back up to 0, I cannot ask another question

Comment: That's what's supposed to happen; if you demonstrate you can't write well received questions we don't *want* you asking more. See e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th

Answer (score 0):

Arrow function expressions don't have the context of the current object. Read [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_separate_this).

You need to use:

```
String.prototype.compareTruthy = function(x) {
    .....
}
```

Comment: I rewrote it to show this:  

String.prototype.compareTruthy = function (x)  {
    this.localeCompare(x) == 0 ? true : false;
  }

  console.log("male".compareTruthy("male"));

but it does not display anything in console

Comment: N/m, thank you.  I fixed the latter issue.